# Is there a way of combining duplicate cell is a column and then adding the values of their adjacent column

Tags: excel, duplicates, addition

I would like to combine all duplicate values in a column (column a) and then add their corresponding values in their adjacent column (column b). So if column 'a' had the value 'bob', 'jill', 'bill', 'bob' and the corresponding values in column b were 10, 2, 4, and 9; the result would be column a bob, jill, bill and column b would be 19, 2, 4

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to go with a pivot table for this case:

[image]

- Select your range > Insert > Pivot Table
- Choose where you want to put the table and confirm
- Under fields > Click Name and Value (in my sample)
- Name should go under Rows and Value under Values
- Fiddle around with header names and such if you wish to

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please look at my output here

[image]

Simple solution would be to type following in column

`c:=SUMIFS($B$1:$B$4,$A$1:$A$4,A1)*(COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,A1)=1)`

or name your ranges so a little easier to understand

`=SUMIFS(palesFilled,names,A1)*(COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,A1)=1)`